# SQL SUM group with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server table name tbInvoice look like this:

[image]

And what I expect for the result is something like this :

[image]

The idea is to calculate GRAND TOTAL from total_inv + total_1 + total_2 where status is 0 (status_inv, status_1, status_2) for all rows group by VENDOR.

I did something like this but didn't work :

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN total_inv = 0 AND total_1 = 0, and total_2 = 0 THEN (total_inv + total_1 + total_2)  
          WHEN total_inv = 0 AND total_1 = 0, and total_2 = 1 THEN (total_inv + total_1)  
          WHEN total_inv = 0 AND total_1 = 1, and total_2 = 0 THEN (total_inv + total_2)
          WHEN total_inv = 0 AND total_1 = 1, and total_2 = 1 THEN (total_inv)
          WHEN total_inv = 1 AND total_1 = 0, and total_2 = 0 THEN (total_1 + total_2)  
          WHEN total_inv = 1 AND total_1 = 0, and total_2 = 1 THEN (total_1)  
          WHEN total_inv = 1 AND total_1 = 1, and total_2 = 0 THEN (total_2)
          WHEN total_inv = 1 AND total_1 = 1, and total_2 = 1 THEN 0 END) GRAND TOTAL FROM tbInvoice GROUP BY vendor
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your case expression you don't refer to status_inv, status_1, status_2

Comment: In your `CASE` expression you check which columns are zero and add those up. So you either add 0 or 0+0 or 0+0+0 to your sum and naturally end up with zero. You don't want to check the totals, but the statuses :-)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `DISTINCT` in your query? It's superfluous. As a rule of thumb: When you `SELECT DISTINCT` you probably did something wrong ;-) `SELECT DISTINCT` is useful in some rare situations, but most often instead of adding `DISTINCT` to your select statement, you should rather ask yourself where the duplicates stem from that you need to remove. Most often you'll find you produced those duplicates yourself by joining inappropriately :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confused statuses and totals in your CASE expression. Moreover, you are making it more complicated than necessary. You want to add up a total when its status is 0:

```
SELECT
  vendor, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status_inv = 0 THEN total_inv ELSE 0 END) +
      CASE WHEN status_1   = 0 THEN total_1   ELSE 0 END) +
      CASE WHEN status_2   = 0 THEN total_2   ELSE 0 END)) AS grand_total
FROM tbInvoice
GROUP BY vendor  
ORDER BY vendor;
```

Without any math tricks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The expression is easier as you thought:

```
SELECT vendor, 
       sum( total_inv + total_1 * status_1 + total_2 * status_2) GRAND TOTAL 
FROM tbInvoice 
GROUP BY vendor
```

**Explanation**

In some cases (when status = 0) you don't want to aggregate value to grand total, in other cases (when status = 1) you want. Then, it is as easy as use `value * status` because `value * 0 = 0` and `value * 1 = value`.

**For your information**

On Stack Overflow [screenshots are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), a simple copy-paste text is preferable. Also, I congrats you about to post your work to solution.

**Edited**

From OP comment it looks I should to toggle `status` field.

```
SELECT vendor, 
       sum(   total_inv * (1-status_inv) 
            + total_1   * (1-status_1) 
            + total_2   * (1-status_2)
          ) as GRAND TOTAL 
FROM tbInvoice 
GROUP BY vendor
```

Comment: Actually, when status = 1 I don't want to aggregate value to grand total, and I want to aggregate value if status = 0. But thanks for quick answer.

Comment: LOL @YerryAntonius, ok, I just fixed answer to toggle `status` :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, here I'm getting the sum of all the totals and subtracting the totals after multiplying by status so that the one with status 1 be eliminated, I choose this method to keep this SQL code ANSI,

```
    SELECT vendor, 
    SUM( total_inv + total_1  + total_2 -( total_inv*status_inv + total_1 * status_1 + total_2 * status_2)) as GRAND TOTAL 
    FROM tbInvoice 
    GROUP BY vendor
```